# Working with rows and columns boostrap

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to make this boxes that will hold some text and maybe some img brackground, but boxes won't align like they should on a small screen.

[image: what I'm trying to do haha]

I tried a few things, but text won't align on the botton without destroying the alignment

CSS:

```
.bigbox {
 text-align: center;
  padding: 80px 40px;
}
.bigbox .bigbox-title {

  text-align: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}

.bigbox .bigbox-text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .85;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.smallbox {
 text-align: center;
  padding: 80px 40px;
}
.smallbox.smallbox-title {

  text-align: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}
.smallbox.smallbox-text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .85;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="full-width-container">
        <div class="row no-space-row ">
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg-color-base">
                <div class="bigbox ">
                    <h2 class="bigbox-title">BOX 1</h2>
                    <p class="bigbox-text">DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="smallbox bg-color-purple ">
                    <h2 class="smallbox-title">BOX 1</h2>
                    <p class="smallbox-text">DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>
                 <div class="smallbox bg-color-purple-dark ">
                    <h2 class="smallbox-title">BOX 1</h2>
                    <p class="smallbox-text">DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in this is `display:flex` on the parent div. This is forcing the two child `div`s to be the same height.

I have removed the padding from the second div to move it closer to the big box, then `position:absolute`d the big box title to the bottom of the `div`.

I've also played with the padding a bit to help with styling - but haven't got it styled to look just like the image above.

```css
.row {
  display:flex;
}
.bg-color-base {
  background:red;
}
.bg-color-base + div{
  padding:0;
}
.bg-color-purple {
  background:purple;
}
.bg-color-purple-dark {
  background:blue;
}
.bigbox {
 text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
.bigbox .bigbox-title {

  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}

.bigbox .bigbox-text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .85;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.smallbox {
 text-align: center;
  padding: 160px 40px 10px;
}
.smallbox.smallbox-title {

  text-align: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}
.smallbox.smallbox-text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .85;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="full-width-container">
        <div class="row no-space-row ">
            <div class="col-xs-6 bg-color-base">
                <div class="bigbox ">
                    <h2 class="bigbox-title">BOX 1</h2>
                    <p class="bigbox-text">DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="smallbox bg-color-purple ">
                    <h2 class="smallbox-title">BOX 2</h2>
                    <p class="smallbox-text">DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>
                 <div class="smallbox bg-color-purple-dark ">
                    <h2 class="smallbox-title">BOX 3</h2>
                    <p class="smallbox-text">DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is working great, thanks! But how can I make it responsive? when you try it in a small screen, they keep being in 2 columns.

Comment: Anyone? I'm stuck with the responsive part. Thanks

Comment: use media queries to turn on / off the flex. Remove it by default, `@media (min-width:768px){ .row { display:flex; /*etc*/ } }`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. The text has to be in an absolutely positioned div.

http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/Kzbeqa

```
.bcenter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```